# After a month, BTC sent from trezor to coinbase never received after 5000 confirmations

Tags: transactions, coinbase.com

On 12/21, I sent 0.75 BTC from Trezor to a valid BTC Coinbase address. The transaction is stuck. It has over 5000 confirmations but Coinbase.com never received the BTC. Both Trezor and Coinbase have been of zero help. Can someone please help me?

Here is the link of the [transaction](https://btc-bitcore5.trezor.io/tx/a2e4d84da4a87c27b9f0f6c166ef74359e2ad2c7b43eab407960d16b5af4e7d7)

Thank you!

Comment: Your tx confirmed in the blockchain, you'll need to contact Coinbase in order to have your account credited (or your coins refunded, etc).

Comment: What did Coinbase say?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It was a valid coinbase address. Both coinbase and Trezor have been zero help. They could care less. It happened that crazy day when cloinbase shutdown and when it was open many people couldn't trade. I'm screwed. I can't wait until wallets like pillar allow you to bypass exchanges to trade. In time coinbase will be out of business.

Answer (score 0):

Coinbase is custodial bitcoin wallet so they don't give you access to your bitcoin private keys or anything. they're just like PayPal. you have numbers in your account, and you can't go to the bank and withdraw these funds. unlike non-custodial bitcoin wallets. they're better for anyone who is looking for bitcoin wallet.

So, what I'm trying to say these types of issues could happen with those wallets and nobody in here can help you get your money back.

Contacting coinbase.com could be the solution and consider changing your bitcoin wallet.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the correct address that you got from Coinbase.com, then your transaction cleared a long time ago. If Coinbase says no, then either you or them are missing something. The only thing I can think is that you sent to the wrong address.

Answer (score 0):

Being that the transaction has more than 10 confirmations it should have been in you wallet a long time ago. Have you thought of looking at a explorer and seeing if the transaction ever made it or was processed?

Try - https://www.blockchain.info